# Jquery fade and swap an element when clicked which will also relate to an accordian menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, fadein, fadeout

You will notice when you click posture 1 the description drops down and images appear on the right. Now when you click posture 2 or posture 3 the images and description change as they should.

[view website](http://www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/about-bikram-yoga/postures-benefits.html)

What I need to do now is -

If posture 1 has been clicked and then posture 2 is clicked the posture 1 menu needs to close so that there is only one posture description visible at one time.

If I could also make it so that if the current open posture item is clicked so that it closes and there are no open posture descriptions that there also no images displayed on the right.

Finally is there a way to make sure only one set of animation images is running, because just say the user goes through all 26 options and they continue to run in the background it may get sluggish (thanks to Nick Craver for bringing that up).

At this stage only posture 1, 2 and 3 are available. Ok finally some code -

```
//Description drop-down boxes
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click
$("h5.trigger").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});

//Slide up and down on click
$("h5.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

});

//Images on the right fade in and out thanks to aSeptik
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#section_Q_01,#section_Q_02,#section_Q_03').hide();

```
    $(function() {
        $('h5.trigger a').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var trigger_id = $(this).parent().attr('id'); //get id Q_##
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide(); //add a class for easy access & hide
        $('#section_' +  trigger_id).addClass('current').fadeIn(5000); //show clicked one
    });
});
```

});

```
//Fading pics
```

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pics').cycle({ 
        fx:    'fade', 
        speed:  2500 
    });
});

Description boxes -

```
<h5 class="trigger" id="Q_01" ><a href="#">Posture 1 : Standing Deep Breathing :</a></h5>
                        <div class="toggle_container" >
                            <div class="block">
                            <span class="sc">Pranayama Series</span>
                            <p class="bold">Benefits:</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h5  class="trigger" id="Q_02" ><a href="#">Posture 2 : Half Moon Pose With Hands To Feet Pose :</a></h5>
                        <div class="toggle_container">
                            <div class="block">
                            <span class="sc">Ardha Chandrasana with Pada-Hastasana</span>
                            <p class="bold">Benefits:</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h5 class="trigger" id="Q_03" ><a href="#">Posture 3 : Awkward Pose :</a></h5>
                        <div class="toggle_container">
                            <div class="block">
                            <span class="sc">Utkatasana</span>
                            <p class="bold">Benefits:</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and the images on the right -

```
 <div id="section_Q_01" class="01">
                        <div class="pics"> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose1/Pranayama._01.jpg"/> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose1/Pranayama._02.jpg"/> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose1/Pranayama._03.jpg"/> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>


                    <div id="section_Q_02" class="02">
                        <div class="pics"> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose2/Half_Moon_Pose_04.jpg" /> 
                            <img  src="../images/multi/poses/pose2/Backward_Bending_05.jpg" /> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose2/Hands_to_Feet_Pose_06.jpg" /> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>  

                    <div id="section_Q_03" class="03">
                        <div class="pics"> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose3/Awkward_01.jpg" /> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose3/Awkward_02.jpg" /> 
                            <img src="../images/multi/poses/pose3/Awkward_03.jpg" /> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

It would be a bonus if images faded out when another element is clicked... but not a big deal.

Thanks for having a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aceze/28
**SOURCE** http://jsbin.com/aceze/28/edit

JQUERY CODE:

```
$(function() {  
$('h5.trigger a').click( function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
//TOGGLE PART
 $('.block').slideUp(400); 
  if( $(this).parent().next().is(':hidden') ){
      $(this).parent().next().slideDown(400);
  }
//DISPLAY HIDE BASED ON CLICK
var trigger_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
$('.current').removeClass('current').hide();
$('#section_' +  trigger_id).addClass('current').fadeIn(500);
// IMAGE SLIDER
$('#section_' +  trigger_id +' .pics img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('#section_' +  trigger_id +' .pics :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('#section_' +  trigger_id +' .pics');}, 
      3000);
  });
});​
```

HTML TOGGLE PART MUST LOOK LIKE THIS

```
<div class="toggle_container">
 <h5 class="trigger" id="Q_01" ><a href="#">Posture 1 : Standing:</a></h5> 
   <div class="block" style="display: none">
       <span class="sc">Pranayama Series</span>
         <p class="bold">Benefits:</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great thanks again!! I just have two small issues now. Is it possible to make the image disappear when all the sliders are closed?  For some of the postures there is only 1 photo when that posture is chosen, can it just stop on the 1st photo so it doesn't fade to white. I have created an example the 3rd option has 1 photo http://jsbin.com/emoba5/2/edit   And finally are you a freelancer? Cheers, Nik

Comment: I have created another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751068/jquery-stop-image-slider-when-accordian-menu-is-closed I would prefer to give you the kudos as its basically your code =)