# jquery stop image slider when accordian menu is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider, jquery-ui-accordion

[http://jsbin.com/emoba5/3/edit click here to view demo](http://jsbin.com/emoba5/3/edit)

Does anybody know how to make the image slider go blank if all menu items are closed? Our how to make it stop on the first image if there is only one image, i.e. posture 3

Im stumped?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sussed.

Nick Craver also offered a solution to keeping the slider action smooth.

http://jsbin.com/emoba5/6/edit